# return new array and increment all values by 10

Tags: java, arrays

I have copied the original array in the plusTen() method, added 10 to each value in the array and I am now trying to call newArray in the main methodand then print it. It has to something simple I am overlooking.

public class mod4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int min;
    int max;

    // Creates array
    int[] array = new int[10];

    //Fills array
    array[0] = 10;
    array[1] = 25;
    array[2] = 34;
    array[3] = 16;
    array[4] = 86;
    array[5] = 13;
    array[6] = 47;
    array[7] = 50;
    array[8] = 26;
    array[9] = 75;

    //Prints original array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
    }
    //Prints Minimum
    System.out.println("Mimimum: " + minNum(array));
    //Prints Maximum
    System.out.println("Maximum: " + maxNum(array));

    int[] newArray = plusTen(int array
    );

  //Print new array       
           for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(newArray[i] + " ");
    }

}

//Finds Minimum value
public static int minNum(int[] array) {

    int min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i > array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }

    return min;

}

//Finds maximum value
public static int maxNum(int[] array) {
    int max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
//Adds ten to values in array

public static int plusTen(int[] array) {

    //makes copy of array
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    //adds 10 to values in new array
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = newArray[i] + 10;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You overlooked that you need to explain the problem if you want people to be able to help..

Comment: Why do you suddenly think that you need to pass arguments like this: `plusTen(int array)`?

Comment: Being condescending to people who are trying to learn isn't helpful. You both overlooked that.

Comment: Don't get caught up in the tone of the comment. They're both making important points, neither of which you've addressed.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I was pointing out what I was trying to do. I thought it was obvious that my problem was with calling the newArray in the main method. As for the other problems shmosel found, I cant indicate I have a problem with them if I dont know that they are problems.

Comment: @Tom I didn't SUDDENLY think anything. I am new to this and was unaware that I was doing it incorrectly.

Comment: You said what you were trying to do, then pasted your code. You should also have described the errors you got, or the difference between your expected and actual output. At the risk of being condescending again, here is some recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes:

1. `plusTen` should return `int[]`, not `int`.
2. The two loops are redundant. You can copy and add at the same time.
3. You need a `return` statement at the end of the method.
4. `int` doesn't belong when you call `plusTen(array)`.

Try this:

```
//...

    int[] newArray = plusTen(array);

//...

public static int[] plusTen(int[] array) {

    //makes copy of array plus 10
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i] + 10;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: @user3403708 If this solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/304954) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    .....

    //Prints original array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
    }

    plusTen(array);
    System.out.println("---Changed Array ----");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
    }

}

public static void plusTen(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i] + 10;
    }
}
```